# Every infinite subset of E has a limit point E

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I know that in Euclidean Spaces, **E is compact** is equivalent to **Every infinite subset of E has a limit point in E**. But I am wondering the following example

> $S = \{0\} \cup\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n = 1,2,3,...\}$

I know that $S$ is compact, thus I think there should be a limit point for its infinite subset

> L = $\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n = 1,2,3,...\}$

But I have a hard time finding $L$'s limit point. (In my opinion, the only limit point for $S$ is $0$, but it is removed in $L$, thus I don't think there is a limit point in $L$). I think I must make a mistake in my reasoning, can someone please point out where I get it wrong?

Comment: $L \subset =E $ so L has limit points in **E**.  Not necessarily in L.

Comment: @fleablood yeah, thanks, I think you are correct.

Comment: Yeah, having all limit points in L would i) mean every infinite subset is closed and ii) mean if we removed just one limit point of E it won't be a limit point of L which ...won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit point of L is 0.  And 0 is in S.  There's no issue.